# Copy from source sql database to destination sql database

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema

I have to copy data from one SQL Server database to other SQL Server database.

There are columns such as Identity and other data types that exist in destination SQL Server DB but not in source database. Source table has only term column, but destination table has id (identity) and term column.

During copy I am getting error like:

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Terms' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

```
string colNames = "";
foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    colNames += col.ColumnName + ",";
}
colNames = colNames.Remove(colNames.Length - 1, 1);
sqlCmd2.Parameters.Clear();

bool hasIdentityCol = false;
sqlCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


sqlCmd2.CommandText = "SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('" + row["Table_Name"] + "'), 'TableHasIdentity')";
if (sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar() != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
{
    hasIdentityCol = true;
}


if (hasIdentityCol == true)
{
    sqlCmd2.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT  dbo." + row["Table_Name"] + " ON";
    sqlCmd2.Transaction = sqlTran;
    sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

sqlCmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO   " + txtDestinationDatabase.Text + ".dbo." + row["Table_Name"] + "(" + colNames + ")  SELECT " + colNames + " FROM " + txtSourceDatabase.Text + ".dbo." + row["Table_Name"];
sqlCmd2.Transaction = sqlTran;
sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (hasIdentityCol == true)
{
    sqlCmd2.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + txtDestinationDatabase.Text + ".dbo." + row["Table_Name"] + " OFF";
    sqlCmd2.Transaction = sqlTran;
    sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with MS Access?  Also, what are the definitions of both the source and destination tables?  You mentioned not having an identity in the source, so what column are you trying to insert into the destination identity column?  It's possible this column should not be included and left to populate itself.

Comment: Actual task is to copy MS Access data to sql server. The sql database schema is changed.Table in MS Access has field term only and sql DB has ID(Identity),Term fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you turne `IDENTITY_INSERT` on you have to specify values for the identity column. You say that your source table does not have a column that could be copied into the identity column. To make this work, just remove the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` statements and only copy the columns you actually have.

If there are additional columns that are not nullable, you might have to hard-code values for those.

Comment: I have about 200 tables to copy their data. It will be difficult to hard code every thing.

Comment: How is an automated process supposed to figure out what values you want in columns without you specifying them? I don't think SQL Server is capable of mind reading yet, so you will have to bite the bullet here and setup some kind of hardcoding scheme. This could be table driven however - that way it is not quite as daunting.   --- The hardcoding is only required if you have non nullable columns in the target tables that are not part of the source. If all your columns are nullable, just remove the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` code as I mentioned before.